# Micronaut @Refreshable not working as expected

Tags: java, micronaut

I'm trying to set up a micronaut service with a Consul configuration. When the service starts it successfully initializes the property of the bean with the value provided from the key-value store. However it doesn't reload when the value changes, even if the refresh is triggered manually.
Here's the bean:

```
@Refreshable
public class ConfigBean {

  @Property(name = "welcome-message")
  private String message = "doe!";

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    String text = this + "Scattered Clouds " + LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yy HH:mm.ss.SSS"));
    System.out.println(text + "\r\n" + this.message);
  }
}
```

And here is the simple controller endpoint:

```
@Controller("/p")
public class Controller {

  @Inject
  ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Inject
  private ConfigBean config;

  @Get("/r")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String refresh() {
    applicationContext.publishEvent(new RefreshEvent());
    return "Hello World";
  }

  @Get("/m")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String message() {
    return config.getMessage();
  }
}
```

With this code what happens is

- value is successfully resolved from config store and shown when navigating to localhost:8080/p/m
- when getting localhost:8080/p/r for manual refresh interestingly enough the init() method of the config bean is called but the value in the message attribute is not updated

What is needed to re-trigger the update of the bean? Is there maybe an implicit call that can be used to purge a config-cache so it is fetched again?

The documentation is a bit sparse about this (Version 2.2.0 was used), thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the same happen if you use the approach shown at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/f86b73a6d7d652c42fc5ff41b39e38d90a7044b2/management/src/main/java/io/micronaut/management/endpoint/refresh/RefreshEndpoint.java#L62?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, when manually using the ApplicationEventPublisher this works as expected! Security was turned on and I did not check the return code with curl -i, adjusted the problem description accordingly. The ApplicationContext publishEvent was originally from https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2019/04/15/micronaut-tutorial-beans-and-scopes/ .

Comment: It does not refresh if the force flag is true I just found out, if environment.refresh() is called just like refreshAndDiff it updates as expected.